# Elements won't float properly

Tags: html, css, css-float, floating

When I make an attempt to float my paragraph to the left this happens: [image]

With this code:

```css
 /* Story styles */

       #story {
          height: 872px;
        }

       /* Paragraph stles  */
        div#story p {
         float: left;
         display: block;
         color: #666666;
         font-size: 26px;
         font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Regular, sans-serif;
         width: 424.667px;
        }

        /* Right div */

        div#right {
         width: auto;
         float: left;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="container" id="quick"> 
                <div id="nav-logo">
                    <img src="site_logo.png" alt="Site Logo" />
                </div>   
            </div>
            
            <div class="container">
            <div id="story">
                            <p>
                               At Robeks, every choice you make is a goodone! 
                             You can trust us to make delicious, good-for-you 
                            smoothies and juices using only the best fruits,
                        fresh vegetables, and natural ingredients. We believe 
                                you shouldn’t have to sacrifice taste for a 
                            healthy alternative – or health for a tasty one. 
                           We make it easy and enjoyable to take good care of 
                                yourself.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                        Whatever you choose is guaranteed to be as nutritious 
                              as it is tasty and delicious. A small choice at 
                       Robeks makes a big difference. Trust Robeks to create 
                         hand-crafted, great-tasting, nutritious alternatives 
                        that will keep you energized and satisfied. You have 
                     enough choices to make in a day. Robeks is an easy one.
                            </p>
                    
                    <div id="right">
                        <img src="about2017.jpg" alt="menu image" />
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

And without the "display: block" & "float: left" on the p element the browser displays:

```css
/* Story styles */

#story {
    height: 872px;
}

/* Paragraph stles  */
div#story p {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Regular, sans-serif;
    width: 424.667px;
}

/* Right div */

div#right {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
            <div id="story">
                            <p>
                                At Robeks, every choice you make is a good one! 
                                You can trust us to make delicious, good-for-you 
                                smoothies and juices using only the best fruits,
                                fresh vegetables, and natural ingredients. We believe 
                                you shouldn’t have to sacrifice taste for a 
                                healthy alternative – or health for a tasty one. 
                                We make it easy and enjoyable to take good care of 
                                yourself.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Whatever you choose is guaranteed to be as nutritious 
                                as it is tasty and delicious. A small choice at 
                                Robeks makes a big difference. Trust Robeks to create 
                                hand-crafted, great-tasting, nutritious alternatives 
                                that will keep you energized and satisfied. You have 
                                enough choices to make in a day. Robeks is an easy one.
                            </p>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div id="right">
                        <img src="about2017.jpg" alt="menu image" />
                    </div>
            </div>
```

I know that the second error is probably because of the paragraphs not being floated to the left, but how do I make the paragraphs appear as they are in the second snippet and allow for the image to be stacked beside the two paragraphs.

Goal:[image]

Comment: There is no second photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#story {
    height: 872px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.p-left,.p-right {
    width: 65%;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
  .p-div {
    width: 76.5%;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
div#right {
    width: 23.5%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin: 35px 15px;
}
  div#right img{
  margin: 35px 0px;
  }
    div#story p {
     display: inline-block;
     color: #666666;
     font-size: 26px;
     margin:20px 0px;
     font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Regular, sans-serif;
     width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="story">
                     <div class="p-div"> <div class="p-left">  <p>
                           At Robeks, every choice you make is a goodone! 
                         You can trust us to make delicious, good-for-you 
                        smoothies and juices using only the best fruits,
                    fresh vegetables, and natural ingredients. We believe 
                            you shouldn’t have to sacrifice taste for a 
                        healthy alternative – or health for a tasty one. 
                       We make it easy and enjoyable to take good care of 
                            yourself.
                          </p></div>
                        <div class="p-right"><p>
                    Whatever you choose is guaranteed to be as nutritious 
                          as it is tasty and delicious. A small choice at 
                   Robeks makes a big difference. Trust Robeks to create 
                     hand-crafted, great-tasting, nutritious alternatives 
                    that will keep you energized and satisfied. You have 
                 enough choices to make in a day. Robeks is an easy one.
                            </p></div></div>

                <div id="right">
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRAK2t25vgyB-4HiONQrDtU9MVaptLiRk3PWPeUUEypBUVT1RYG0Q" alt="menu image"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRAK2t25vgyB-4HiONQrDtU9MVaptLiRk3PWPeUUEypBUVT1RYG0Q" alt="menu image"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRAK2t25vgyB-4HiONQrDtU9MVaptLiRk3PWPeUUEypBUVT1RYG0Q" alt="menu image"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRAK2t25vgyB-4HiONQrDtU9MVaptLiRk3PWPeUUEypBUVT1RYG0Q" alt="menu image">
                </div>
   
                
        </div>

                
        </div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusions but what I want is for the image to be stacked beside the two paragraphs

Comment: how about now ?

Comment: do you wan't to be responsive !

Comment: The two paragraphs should be floated to the left as shown in the second snippet, and the image should be stacked beside it on the right.

Comment: you can add more images and more <p>

Comment: Not sure what that means or how that would work, but if you need a reference as to what I'm trying to get, I've added a photo above.

Comment: Now it's as in the image !

Comment: do you wan't to be responsive !

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: if i have answered you question please make it as resolved 
and if you wan't your text to be on all screen handled "that what responsive mean"
i can help you with that

Comment: No I just want the text on the left and the image on the right